# llamar de otra manera a el objeto

Tags: javascript, json, poo, objeto, alert

Cuando creo un objeto en Json y lo inserto en texto aparece como `[object Object]`

```
var p = { hola:"hola" };

alert(p);  //lanza [object Object]
```

¿Es posible cambiar `[object Object]` por `[object p]`?

Comment: Debes convertir ese objeto a una cadena *que se pueda interpretar*, mete a p dentro de `JSON.stringify(p)` y con eso obtendrás lo que esperas

Comment: Si lo que estas preguntando es modificar el comportamiento de la consola al devolver un objeto a texto, la respuesta es NO, no puedes cambiar directamente la forma en la que la consola del navegador te devuelve es string del objeto, si puedes, como indican los compis convertirlo en JSON y mostrarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Tu objeto no se está pasando a una cadena, debes de convertirlo, te lo dejo acá:

```
var p = { hola:"hola" };

var pJson = JSON.stringify(p);

alert(pJson);
```

Referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify

Comment: Aunque es correcta, existen mejores fuentes de consulta: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify si la cambias te voto positivo

Comment: Por otro lado Daniel, no es bien visto pedirle al OP en la respuesta que te la marque como aceptada, si le es útil eso lo decidirá el

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración BetaM, soy nuevo en Stack :)

Comment: ¿pero como es posible hacer que cuando se haga un alert en lugar de decir object Object diga un texto pesonalizado?`alert(p)// en lugar de  [object Object] lance [objeto P]` ¿se podra?

Comment: Podrías probar con: alert(pJson.hola); y me cuentas.

Comment: me lanza undefined

Comment: Pasame tu código para poderte ayudar y dar con el problema

Comment: `var p = { hola:"hola" }; var pJson = JSON.stringify(p);
 alert(pJson.hola);` es el codigo que me dijiste como pusiera

Comment: Tienes razón, ya que quieres mostrar directo el mensaje de tu objeto, en vez de `alert(pJson.hola)` pon:  `window.alert(p.hola);`